# Pandas: How to drop multiple columns with nan as col name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

As per the title here's a reproducible example:

```
raw_data = {'x': ['this', 'that', 'this', 'that', 'this'], 
            np.nan: [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
            'y': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
            np.nan: [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['x', np.nan, 'y', np.nan])
df

   x     NaN  y    NaN
0  this  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  that  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  this  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  that  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  this  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Aim is to drop only the columns with `nan` as the col name (so keep column `y`). `dropna()` doesn't work as it conditions on the `nan` values *in* the column, not `nan` as the col name.

`df.drop(np.nan, axis=1, inplace=True)` works if there's a single column in the data with `nan` as the col name, but not with multiple columns with `nan` as the col name, as in my data.

So how to drop multiple columns where the col name is `nan`?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
In [218]: df = df.loc[:, df.columns.notna()]

In [219]: df
Out[219]:
      x   y
0  this NaN
1  that NaN
2  this NaN
3  that NaN
4  this NaN
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
df.columns = df.columns.fillna('to_drop')
df.drop('to_drop', axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

### As of pandas 1.4.0

`df.drop` is the simplest solution, as it now handles multiple `NaN` headers properly:

```py
df = df.drop(columns=np.nan)

#    x     y
# 0  this  NaN
# 1  that  NaN
# 2  this  NaN
# 3  that  NaN
# 4  this  NaN
```

Or the equivalent `axis` syntax:

```py
df = df.drop(np.nan, axis=1)
```

Note that it's possible to use `inplace` instead of assigning back to `df`, but `inplace` is not recommended and [will eventually be deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529).

Comment: This won't work with float64 nans. I found that the hard way, when loading Excel files with notes outside data

Comment: Hmm, not sure I follow? If I change OP's example to `np.float64('nan')`, it still works fine on my end. I also made a dummy xlsx with some notes outside the data, and `read_excel` labels the extra columns as "Unnamed: #" instead of nans, so that seems like a different scenario?