# How to convert a pandas DataFrame into one-hot encoded?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume, I have a DataFrame with million rows. Here, each row represents one shopper, each number in each cell denotes item code. There are approximately 250 items in the data base. A toy table is like following

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame({'item1':[10, 10, 22, 89],
                   'item2':[15, 35, 33, 103],
                   'item3':[np.NaN, 65, 47, 41],
                   'item4':[np.NaN, np.NaN, 10, 22]})
df
```

| item1 | item2 | item3 | item4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 15 | NaN | NaN |
| 10 | 35 | 65 | NaN |
| 22 | 33 | 47 | 10 |
| 89 | 103 | 41 | 22 |

The goal is to convert the above table into a one-hot encoded table/DataFrame (each row still represents one shopper) such as

| 1 | ... | 10 | ... | 15 | ... | 250 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | ... | 1 | ... | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | ... | 0 | ... | 0 |

Thus, the final data frame shape is something like (1000000, 250). Is there a way to convert a DataFrame into a one-hot encoded table quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sklearn's [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html):

- Set `sparse=False` since you want dense 2D output
- [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with some numeric value (e.g., -1) and drop that column afterwards

  - Note: In pandas 1.4+, skip this step since it's now [easy to drop NaN column names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71192360/13138364)
- [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) to aggregate the duplicate columns (thanks to [@enke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17521785/enke))

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
e = encoder.fit_transform(df.fillna(-1))

out = pd.DataFrame(e,
    columns=np.hstack(encoder.categories_).astype(int),
    index=encoder.feature_names_in_,
    dtype=int,
).drop(columns=[-1]).groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
```

Output:

```
        10   15   22   33   35   41   47   65   89   103
item1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
item2    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0     0
item3    1    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0     0
item4    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1     1
```

Comment: Do you need to `groupby` on the columns, since you now have 2 10s, 2 22s etc.?

Answer (score 3):

The `melt` method might be useful.

### Code:

#### # Solution 1

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

# Create the sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'item1':[10, 10, 22, 89], 'item2':[15, 35, 33, 103], 'item3':[np.NaN, 65, 47, 41], 'item4':[np.NaN, np.NaN, 10, 22]})

# Transform the df into one-hot-encoding
df = df.melt(ignore_index=False).reset_index().pivot_table('variable', 'index', 'value', aggfunc='count').fillna(0)

print(df)
```

#### # Solution 2

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

# Create the sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'item1':[10, 10, 22, 89], 'item2':[15, 35, 33, 103], 'item3':[np.NaN, 65, 47, 41], 'item4':[np.NaN, np.NaN, 10, 22]})

# Transform the df into one-hot-encoding
df = pd.get_dummies(df.melt(ignore_index=False).value).groupby(level=0).max()

print(df)
```

### Output:

| 10.0 | 15.0 | 22.0 | 33.0 | 35.0 | 41.0 | 47.0 | 65.0 | 89.0 | 103.0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Perhaps you might want to make a `SparseDataFrame` because of its size.

Comment: Yes. I believe the final data frame will be very sparse.  plus the item code does not increase by 1 at a time. Thank you very much for your quick response. I will try it ASAP.

Comment: FYI: Added another solution inspired by enke's answer.

Comment: I try both of your solutions. They are very straightforward and clear. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, in the original DataFrame, the rows already represent shoppers, right? Then we could convert each entry in `df` to strings and use `pd.get_dummies`; then sum across to get a single column for each item:

```
out = pd.get_dummies(df.astype(str))
out.columns = out.columns.str.split('_').str[1].str.split('.').str[0]
out = out.drop(columns='nan').groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
```

Output:

```
   10  103  15  22  33  35  41  47  65  89
0   1    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
2   1    0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
3   0    1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1
```

Comment: This is possible, but you do lose some information this way. For example, this makes it look like `item1` only has 1 occurrence of 10 when it has 2 occurrences.

Comment: @tdy item10 has 3 occurrences, no? For shoppers 0,1,3?

Comment: Ah you're right, I had a brain lapse. The final `groupby` does make sense.